# Separar valores repetidos de una columna en csv Python

Tags: python, csv

estoy queriendo trabajar con un CSV en Python.

```
ID           Inventory    Domain                   Requests   Impressions      Fill Rate
123456       auto         neighborhoodscout.com      11402        26            0.23
123456       auto         sinembargo.mx              10334        24            0.23
123456       auto         elsalvadortimes.com        9893         17            0.17
155444       camioneta    thealternativedaily.com    51389        81            0.16
155444       camioneta    heywise.com                45578       135            0.3
155444       camioneta    wis.pr                     28792        69            0.24
```

Esos son mis valores del CSV. Necesito crear un CSV por cada campo de Inventory. Basicamente seria un csv con los 3 datos de auto y otro con los 3 de camioneta en este caso. Soy bastante nuevo en Python y se leer y extraer data de un csv el problema es cuando tengo que hacer lo que pido anteriormente! Vale aclarar que si o si tengo que trabajar leyendo el CSV que tengo con toda la data.

Desde ya muchas gracias.

Saludos

Comment: Martin ¿Puedes usar Pandas? Seria muy simple. ¿O solo el módulo csv de Python? ¿El separador del csv son comas ( ',' ) u otro separador?

Comment: Sisi puedo usar pandas o cualquier Import el unico tema es que tengo que trabajar con el csv descargado! Y si, son comas el separador (',')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para crear un csv por cada grupo de tu primera columna puedes usar `pandas.groupby` para crear los grupos y luego guardar cada uno en un csv con el nombre del grupo con `pandas.to_csv`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("datos.csv",  header=0,  sep = ",")
for group in df.groupby(df["Inventory"]):
    group[1].to_csv("{}.csv".format(group[0]), sep=',', index=False)
```

Suponiendo que tu csv se llamara "datos.csv" obtendriamos dos archivos:

**auto.csv:**

```
Inventory                  Domain   Requests    Impressions  Fill Rate
auto        neighborhoodscout.com      11402             26       0.23
auto                sinembargo.mx      10334             24       0.23
auto          elsalvadortimes.com       9893             17       0.17
```

**camioneta.csv:**

```
Inventory                  Domain   Requests    Impressions  Fill Rate
camioneta thealternativedaily.com      51389             81       0.16
camioneta             heywise.com      45578            135        0.3
camioneta                  wis.pr      28792             69       0.24
```

No importa los grupos que existan , por cada uno se creara un csv con el nombre del grupo de forma automática.

Cada grupo retornado por `groupby` es una tupla donde el primer elemento es el identificador del grupo y el segundo el DataFrame que se corresponde a ese grupo.

Comment: Lo probe pero me da este error: IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: ' auto.csv'

Comment: Le agregue una 'w' luego del datos.csv, para que me escriba el archivo y obtuve el siguente error :TypeError: to_csv() got multiple values for keyword argument 'sep'.

Comment: @MartinBouhier solo tienes que tocar la linea `df = pd.read_csv("datos.csv",  header=0,  sep = ",")` cambiando  "datos.csv" por la ruta de tu csv original (el que tiene todas las columnas ), no añadir nada más. `to_csv` ya sobrescribe los archivos si existen. Los nombres "auto" y "camioneta" no se los tienes que dar, los toma de los grupos de forma automática. He probado el script con tu csv y funciona perfectamente. Si te sigue dando error pon el código que estas usando tal cual.

Comment: Ya esta solucionado. Tenia un error con un espacio adelante de uno de los grupos! Muchas gracias!!!!!

Comment: Me saltan estos errores cuando tengo algun campo que tiene simbolos como _ o / IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'GDM MW $2 05/09.csv'. Sabes como puedo solucionarlo>

Comment: Nono, Mac. Pude ser que tenga que encodearlo? me dijeron eso

Comment: Dale, espero tu respuesta. Gracias

Comment: Joder.... hoy ya no pienso bien, tan obvio y tardo 10 minutos en  verlo :( ..... 'GDM MW $2 05/09.csv"..... La barra inclinada / causa que sea interpretado como una ruta.... por eso dice que no existe... Con `"{}.csv".format(group[0]).replace("/",  "_")` se soluciona (cambiamos "/" por un carácter válido como "_"). Si tienes posibilidad de que tengas más caracteres inválidos lo suyo es crear una expresión regular y eliminarlos o substituirlos de los nombres de los ficheros.
 
@MartinBouhier

Comment: Encontre una forma mejor para solucionarlo. Ahi cambie la pregunta y agregue el ID para el CSV. Inicio el programa y me da los resultados que quiero. Lo unico que me faltaria es que en el nombre de los archivos creados me ponga el del Inventory y no el del ID. Me podrias ayudar con eso??

Answer (score -1):

Considerando que tienes ya generado el archivo `.csv` te recomiendo que recurras a leer las líneas del `.csv` con los métodos de archivos `open("datos.csv", "r")` y `archivo.readlines()`, que separes los valores por sus comas, que selecciones cada clase por su posición y que de ahí generes un archivo para cada clase con `open("nuevo.csv","w")` volviendo a colocar las comas para separar tus valores.

No tengo mucha experiencia en el tema, pero espero poder haberte ayudado!!!

Comment: Hola Carlos, te damos la bienvenida al sitio. Lo que comentas puede servir como respuesta, pero tu publicación ha sido reportada como de baja calidad por la comunidad. Sería ideal si pudieras añadir ejemplos (a ser posible basados en el código de la pregunta) para ver cómo se haría con `open` y `readlines`. Lee sobre cómo crear un [mcve] y completa el [tour] para más información (y con ello ganarás tu primera medalla). Saludos.